# Use CMFCEditBrowseCtrl to select a file?

Tags: mfc

I am unsure if `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` is really designed for this, but I want to employ it as a way to let the user choose a file from a dialog, rather than manually have a button whose handler creates a `CFileDialog`.

The issue I'm having is I want to call an event handler when a file is chosen, but I don't know what event to catch. I tried to use `ON_EN_CHANGE` but this crashed my program - I clicked the button, and before the open-files window appeared, I got I got a weird popup "invalid file choice ??????????" (or similar, I don't have the code here) and when I clicked OK the application ended.

Is this a valid use of the control, and if so what would a minimal sample look like?

Comment: `ON_EN_CHANGE` is the correct way to get the result for `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: What crashed your program? Catching the `ON_EN_CHANGE` event? Or what you did in that handler?

Comment: I updated with more details. So `ON_EN_CHANGE` should be fired after the file is chosen and the file-browser dialog closes?

Comment: You will get `ON_EN_CHANGE` when the text in the edit box is changed by ANY means (user typing, file-browser dlg closing, etc.). When you have that popup, could you break into debugger and see what is in the call stack?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your "minimal sample" question:

- Use MFC App Wizard to generate Dialog app.
- In resource editor, drag `MFC EditBrowse Control` onto the dialog.
- Right-click that control, select `Add Event Handler...`; select `EN_CHANGE` in the `Message type:` list and (optionally) change the `Function handler name:`.
- (Optionally) right-click on the control again and select `Add Variable...`; check `Control variable` checkbox if it was un-checked; type a `Variable name:`, for example `m_browser`.

This will add

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, m_browser);
```

to your `void CMFCDlgDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)`,

```
ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, &CMFCDlgDlg::OnEnChangeMfceditbrowse1)
```

to the message map, and this method:

```
void CMFCDlgDlg::OnEnChangeMfceditbrowse1()
{
}
```

I have added this code to demo that it works:

```
void CMFCDlgDlg::OnEnChangeMfceditbrowse1()
{
    CString str;
    m_browser.GetWindowTextW(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Dialog App. In the Dialog Designer, drag an MFC Edit Control onto your dialog.
2. Right-click the newly placed control and select the **Add
   Variable...** option.
3. In the **Add Control Variable** window that popped up, change the
   **Category** option from **Control** to **Value** and name the variable in
   the **Name** field. E.g. *m_chosen_file*. The type of the variable
   should be *CString*.
4. Click **Finish**.
5. Right-click the control again and select the **Add Event
   Handler...** option.
6. In the **Event Handler** window that popped up, make sure that your
   dialog class is selected in the **Class list** option (it defaults to
   *CAboutDlg* for me, which is not what you want.) The **Message Type**
   option should already be set to **EN_CHANGE**, if not, change it. Then
   click **Ok**.
7. You should now be taken to the code editor, with the cursor in
   the newly added message handler. All you have to do now is add a
   **UpdateData(TRUE);** statement and the name of the chosen file is now in
   the *m_chosen_file* variable.

```cpp
void CBrowseEditDlg::OnEnChangeMfceditbrowse1()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE); // This call sends data from the dialog
                      // controls to the attached member variables,
                      // in this case the chosen file name. 
                      // Use FALSE to send data the opposite direction.

    // Do something with the file name
    AfxMessageBox(_T("You chose ") + m_chosen_file);
}
```